# StackExchange.Redis server.Keys(pattern:"IsVerySlow*")

Tags: stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm new to redis so I'm doing something wrong, I'm sure:

I've stored roughly 16,000 key/values in Azure Redis.

I used the following to write the keys/values

```
      foreach (var worksheet in wksList)
      {
        var wksYYMM = string.Format("{0}{1:00}", worksheet.ReviewDt.Year, worksheet.ReviewDt.Month);
        var wksKey = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", provCode, wksYYMM, worksheet.AcctNbr);
        string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( MakeWsListDto(worksheet, provCoderList, rvrList));
        cache.StringSet(wksKey, jsonStr);
      }
```

so my keys look like this:
"AP:201401:AZ5798BK"

When I try a lookup like:

```
    var keys = server.Keys(pattern: "AP:201401:*"); // returns in milliseconds
    var keyAry = keys.ToArray(); // returns in over one minute
    (note: this returns 12 keys)
```

it takes 1 min 12 seconds to return the keys. Once I have the keys it takes milliseconds to retrieve the values for those.  If I iterate over the value of keys and return the values I get a similar result.  I did a ToArray() just to isolate the problem.

If I try the same query in redis-cli.exe it comes back in milliseconds.

Am I using this command incorrectly?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`server.Keys` automatically selects between `KEYS` and the preferred `SCAN` based on server version. I suspect what is happening is that you are thus using `SCAN` with a too-small page-size. There is an optional parameter for page size. Try specifying something considerably larger than the default - hundreds, thousands, etc. If not specified, the page-size uses the Redis `SCAN`  default of `10`, which could cause a lot of round-trips to be required.

Comment: Thanks Marc I'll give that a try and let you know how it went.  That might explain why the redis-cli.exe is so much quicker.

Comment: Marc! Yes that was the answer. A follow-up question: I did a little optimization testing and found that I continued to get performance boosts with pages sizes through 2000 though it leveled off around 1650.  At that point it leveled off at around 180 milliseconds.  Two questions: Is pagesize optimization a function of the db size or keysize?  Second question: does memory allocation for the pagesize happen on the client or the server?  Thanks very much for your answer!

Comment: This helped me solve a similar performance issue with `server.Keys`. Thanks!

Comment: @weej the trick with setting larger page size dramatically improved performance in our solution! Thx!

Answer (score 12):

Do not use `KEYS` - it is a blocking command that will Render your Redis server unavailable to other request while it is running. Quoting from the [command's documentation](http://redis.io/commands/keys):

> **Warning:** consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in
>   production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance
>   when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended
>   for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace
>   layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're
>   looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider
>   using SCAN or sets.

If you read the warning thoroughly, you'll notice the recommended approaches at the end of the paragraph, namely using [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) or Redis' sets. SCAN is non-blocking but since your question suggests that that you're into performance, I recommend using sets.

The idea is to maintain a Redis set with all the key names that are associated with that "pattern", so in your example you have to do the StackExchange.Redis-equivalent of `SADD AP:201401 AP:201401:AZ5798BK` after your call to `cache.SetString`, e.g.:

```
cache.SetAdd(wksYYMM, wksKey);
```

*Disclaimer: I am not a C# programmer nor am I too familiar with StackExchange.Redis (sorry Marc ;))*

Now, instead of KEYS or SCAN to get your keys, just do `SMEMBERS AP:201401` or probably:

```
var keys = cache.Members(wksYYMM);
```

**Bonus**: since you're actually interested in the values of the these keys, you can use Redis' Lua scripting to fetch the keys values based on the set's members, or just use [SORT](http://redis.io/commands/sort).

Pure Redis:

```
SORT AP:201401 BY nosort GET *`
```

C# & StackExchange.Redis:

```
vals = cache.Sort(wksYYMM, by = "nosort", get = "*");
```

Comment: server.Keys actually uses SCAN automatically if available. More info on separate answer.

Comment: I'm pretty happy with the implementation, I must admit. The enumerable sequence it hands you back scrolls / pages automatically as you work through the data.

Comment: Itamar, thanks for your response.  I'm not sure sets will be appropriate because I actually want to update the items individually and add new ones as they're created.  My understanding is that a set is a single storage item that holds multiple items.  Eventually I want to use pub-sub to update those users interested in keys starting with AP:201410 when a new entry is made in the database.  Then I'd send just that item via SignalR.  For those reasons I want to keep them as separate items.

Answer (score 1):

StackExchange.Redis server.Keys without set pageSize will be very slow.

Try this

```
server.keys( database:0, pattern:"error:*", pageSize: 5000);
```