# .NET Core inject singleton service in another singleton service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using **StackExchange.Redis** to connect to Redis server from .NET Core. How can I inject singleton `IConnectionMultiplexer` to another singleton service?

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(GetRedisConnectionString()));
    services.AddSingleton<IMyService>(new MyService(new DbContext(optionsBuilder.Options)), ???);
    ...
}
```

**MyService.cs**

```
private DbContext _dbContext;
private IConnectionMultiplexer _redis;

public MyService(DbContext dbContext, IConnectionMultiplexer redis)
{
    _dbContext = fitDBContext;
    _redis = redis;
}
```

What do I need to put instead of `???` in `ConfigureServices`? Is there any other approach?

`StackExchange.Redis` suggests ([link](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics)) that we save the returned value of `ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(...)` call and reuse it. Therefore, I created singleton service for it (it is based on another [StackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368234/using-stackexchange-redis-in-a-asp-net-core-controller)) which can be injected, but I am not having any luck injecting it to another SINGLETON service `MyService`.

Comment: use the factory delegate

Comment: @Nkosi Can you provide an example?

Comment: You will run into problems having the dbcontext as a singleton for `IMyService`! Please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767910/entity-framework-core-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previ/48783504#48783504

Comment: @Mark alsami is correct in their observation about using the DbContext in the singleton. There are potential issues there.Have you considered making your service scoped? And also letting the service container manage the lifetime of the context

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Technically, only the `IConnectionMultiplexer` needs to be a singleton. `IMyService` doesn't have to be. The container will hold on to the instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the factory delegate overload for `AddSingleton` when registering the service

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    //...

    services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(GetRedisConnectionString()));
    services.AddSingleton<IMyService>(serviceProvider => 
        new MyService(new DbContext(optionsBuilder.Options), serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConnectionMultiplexer>())
    );

    //...
}
```

The delegate passes in an `IServiceProvider` which can be used to resolve desired services.