# Redis StackExchange delete key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, redis

I am trying to delete a Redis Key. I am using the StackExchange.Redis library and have tried searching on StackOverflow for a way to delete a key. I found this link: [StackExchange Redis delete all keys that start with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247952/stackexchange-redis-delete-all-keys-that-start-with)

But my library does not have a method called Database.KeyDelete. How do I get that method?

```
public void DeleteCacheByKey(string Key)
{
    ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("127.0.0..1:6379");
    var server = redis.GetServer("127.0.0..1:6379");
    redis.Database.KeyDelete(key);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default Redis DB, you should try like this :

```
public void DeleteCacheByKey(string Key)
{
    ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("127.0.0.1:6379");
    redis.GetDatabase().KeyDelete(key);
}
```

Note that the `ConnectionMultiplexer` is `IDisposable`. It should be diposed.