# Why is extracting keys and hashes from Redis so slow?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using the `StackExchange.Redis` library to interface with an Azure Redis server to extract some hash values for access via a web api. Here is how I am doing it:

```
        IDatabase cache = lazyConnection.Value.GetDatabase();
        var server = lazyConnection.Value.GetServer(lazyConnection.Value.GetEndPoints().First());
        var starterKeys = server.Keys(pattern: "Monitor:*");
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var starterKey in starterKeys)
        {
            var hashEntries = cache.HashGetAll(starterKey);
            foreach (var hashEntry in hashEntries)
            {
                //put values into my model here...
            }
            count++;
        }
```

There are exactly 22 keys that match the pattern `"Monitor:*"` (found by debugging and watching the `count` value at the end). However, this snippet of code, **retrieving those 22 keys and hashes takes 55 seconds**. The hash values aren't very large either. There are about 19 key-value pairs in each hash (things like name, company, email, phone, etc. Nothing too big).

Why would this take so long? I thought one of the reasons to use Redis was to be fast, and reduce load from the database by storing aggregated data. I could set this up in my database and query it (even with joins to get the aggregated data), and my process would by considerably faster than 55 seconds.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or am I not understanding the purpose or correct usage of Redis?

And, most importantly, is there anything I can do to retrieve these keys and hash values faster?

Comment: Actually it's recommended to use SCAN according to [document of KEYS command](https://redis.io/commands/keys)

Comment: Yes, but doesn't the `StackOverflow.Redis` library use `SCAN` under the hood? - https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan

Comment: How long for each step? and GetServer / Keys command

Comment: @shingo: GetDatabase:900ms; GetServer:320ms; EnumOnEachKey:250ms - 1500ms

Comment: How many **total** entries are in your Redis database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StackExchange.Redis server.Keys(pattern:"IsVerySlow\*")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26438736/stackexchange-redis-server-keyspatternisveryslow)

Comment: @mjwills: 5452 total keys

Comment: Did @LeisenChang's link help at all?

Comment: The answer provided by @Leisen Change is (I believe) the solution. After increasing page size to 1650, it runs considerably faster.

Comment: Cool, click `close` and choose the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

if you need all KEY*, keeping them in a value will increase the speed. You can keep the object under AllKeys to display all Keys.

SetAllObject

```
 cache.StringSetAsync("AllKeys", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
```

GetAllObject

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TEntity>>(await cache.StringGetAsync("AllKeys")).ToList();
```