# StackExchange.Redis - How to get the type of the key?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to go through the list of dbX in Redis via StackExchange.Redis and look for the particular `type` of the keys. There are `string`, `list`, `set`, `zset`, `hash` types of keys. Lets say I would like to find the `list` types of keys in the `db1`, I tried the following:

```
RedisCacheClient _client;
...
IRedisDatabase database = _client.GetDb(1);
List<InfoDetail> categorizedInfo = await database.GetInfoCategorizedAsync();
IEnumerable<InfoDetail> infos = categorizedInfo.Where(i => i.Category == "Keyspace");
```

This helps me with getting the basic info about the keys `keys=9,expires=0,avg_ttl=0` but not the types.

I can find all the keys:

```
IEnumerable<string> keys = await database.SearchKeysAsync("*");
```

But that gives me only the names, not the types of the keys.
So, how do I find the `type` of the key?.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think I have found the solution.
the `IRedisDatabase` type has the `Database` propery of type `IDatabase`, and `IDatabase` type has `KeyType()` method that I could use (it should have been `GetKeyType()`, I think, which would've made it much easier to find). With that, I was able to list the keys with types:

```
RedisCacheClient _client;
...
IRedisDatabase redisDatabase = _client.GetDb(1);
IEnumerable<string> keys = await redisDatabase.SearchKeysAsync("*");
IDatabase database = redisDatabase.Database;
Dictionary<string, RedisType> keysWithTypes = keys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => database.KeyType(k));
```

the result looks something like this:

```
{[myHash, Hash]}
{[myZSet, SortedSet]}
{[myString, String]}
{[mySet, Set]}
{[mylist, List]}
```

Comment: after some time experimenting around with searching keys, I think it is worth adding that listing all keys from Redis is done better via SCAN, and in StackExchange.Redis, there is server.Keys method that does it in a more efficiant way than SearchKeysAsync("*") from my example. It is explained in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26440148/1694087

Answer (score -1):

Redis has `TYPE` command which gives you the type of the key. I suppose any client would support this.

> Returns the string representation of the type of the value stored at key. The different types that can be returned are: string, list, set, zset, hash and stream.

https://redis.io/commands/type